# Is it possible to use a variable containing column names as strings in expressions for creating new data.table columns

Tags: r, data.table

Is there an easy way to use a variable containing a `data.table` column name (string) in the right hand size of an expression that creates a new `data.table` column?

```r
library(data.table)
mtcars = as.data.table(mtcars)

# Say I have the name of a data.table column stored in a variable
colname = "mpg"


# How could i use this variable to create new columns
# My initial attempt:
mtcars[, `:=` (xMPGBiggerThan20 = colname > 20)]

# I think result is based on "mpg" > 20, rather than using the column values
head(mtcars)
#>     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb xMPGBiggerThan20
#> 1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4             TRUE
#> 2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4             TRUE
#> 3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1             TRUE
#> 4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1             TRUE
#> 5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2             TRUE
#> 6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1             TRUE


# How would I make the command equivalent to if I wrote
mtcars[, `:=` (xMPGBiggerThan20 = mpg > 20)]

# Desired result
head(mtcars)
#>     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb xMPGBiggerThan20
#> 1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4             TRUE
#> 2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4             TRUE
#> 3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1             TRUE
#> 4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1             TRUE
#> 5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2            FALSE
#> 6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1            FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use .SD.

`` mtcars[, `:=` (xMPGBiggerThan20 = .SD > 20), .SDcols = colname] ``

Comment: Thanks Richard! Your answer works and is pure data.table without being dependent on a dev version. Further, I suspect it might be preferable to using `get` (although I could be wrong). For this reason I'll mark it as the answer - but want everyone reading to know @Peace's answer works and once 1.14.3 is on cran is a great solution

Comment: Thank you. Though `get()` works just fine, the [data.table programming vignette](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html) says that `get()` is a "retired interface" and recommends (as Peace suggested) using the new `env` argument. In this particular case though, .SD works nicely too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try  (`data.table 1.14.3`)

```
mtcars[, xMPGBiggerThan20 := colname > 20, env = list(colname = "mpg")][]
```

or

```
mtcars[, `:=` (xMPGBiggerThan20 = colname > 20), env = list(colname = "mpg")][]
```

If you don't want to update to the development version, you can consider to use

```
mtcars[, `:=` (xMPGBiggerThan20 = get(colname) > 20)]
```

PS: You can update to the newest version with `data.table::update.dev.pkg()`

Ref: https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html

Comment: Wow - thanks for the answer Peace! You read my mind with your last edit - I'd prefer to avoid dependency on the dev version. `get` is a new one for me, despite being in base R. It works well for my use case and is what I'll be moving forward with - at least until the dev version of data.table makes its way to cran :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that should work

```
mtcars[["xMPGBiggerThan20"]] <- mtcars[[colname]] > 20
```

The following also produces an identical result

```
mtcars$xMPGBiggerThan20 <- mtcars[[colname]] > 20
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. While your response is correct - I'm actually hoping to stay inside the data.table ecosystem - I'd prefer the data.table to be modified in-place if possible. If i understand correctly (and i might not) that would not be the case with the above